# Drools 6.5 ConcurrentModificationException with LinkedHashMap Fact

Tags: drools

In our Java application using Drools 6.5 final release, we use Disruptor to run the same rules by different user threads, each thread has its own dedicated Session object while all the sessions are created from a common KieBase. Dev/QA did not see the following error but in Production, we see the error: the object being inserted is LinkedHashMap instance and this object will definitely being processed by one user thread (based on hashCode of immutable object coming with the message), so this is strange that this LinkedHashCode object would be modified by thread other than the user threads. Any thoughts on what could be the cause?

07:04:15.719 ERROR [RuleHandler6] erf.SupportsProfilingHandlerBase - Exception -

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedHashIterator.nextNode(LinkedHashMap.java:711)
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedEntryIterator.next(LinkedHashMap.java:744)
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedEntryIterator.next(LinkedHashMap.java:742)
    at java.util.AbstractMap.hashCode(AbstractMap.java:507)
    at org.drools.core.common.EqualityAssertMapComparator.hashCodeOf(EqualityAssertMapComparator.java:46)
    at org.drools.core.util.ObjectHashMap.get(ObjectHashMap.java:90)
    at org.drools.core.common.ClassAwareObjectStore.getHandleForObject(ClassAwareObjectStore.java:150)
    at org.drools.core.common.NamedEntryPoint.getFactHandle(NamedEntryPoint.java:680)
    at consolidator.services.DroolsKieContainer$SessionWrapper.internalFire(DroolsKieContainer.java:198)
    at consolidator.services.DroolsKieContainer$SessionWrapper.fire(DroolsKieContainer.java:175)
    at consolidator.services.DroolsKieService.fire(DroolsKieService.java:153)
    at consolidator.disruptor.RuleHandler.handleFIX(RuleHandler.java:88)
    at consolidator.disruptor.RuleHandler.onEventCore(RuleHandler.java:68)
    at consolidator.disruptor.RuleHandler.onEventCore(RuleHandler.java:15)
    at consolidator.perf.SupportsProfilingHandlerBase.onEvent(SupportsProfilingHandlerBase.java:43)
    at consolidator.perf.SupportsProfilingHandlerBase.onEvent(SupportsProfilingHandlerBase.java:9)
    at com.lmax.disruptor.BatchEventProcessor.run(BatchEventProcessor.java:129)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Well, we don't know how your Production differs from other deployments, but this exception is definitely seeing modifications _after_ the Iterator is created. Look hard at the lifecycle of the Iterator.

Comment: QA just reproduced the problem with the perflab. Each user thread has its own session and no two user threads can operate on the same LinkedHashMap object. Definitely there is another thread accesses or modify the LinkedHashMap object: could that be Drools internal threads that we are not aware of? Since the object has not been inserted into Drools internal store, so this behavior is very strange.

Comment: I think I figured out what is going on. When the LinkedHashMap object is submitted to a groups of handler, we access one of the immutable value of the Map, so while one of handler can already access and process it, the other handler could be still in get() method; resulting in the exception.

Comment: This should be an Answer to the question! Get that sweet, sweet rep.

Comment: Suffered a setback yesterday: it turned out the the accessOrder of the LinkedHashMap is false; so mere access of the entry through get() will not result in the exception. The object was in fact being processed by multiple RuleHandler threads: added more logging, hopefully this would be reproduced by QA.

Comment: I'm not sure of the details, but be aware you cannot depend on the ConcurrentModificationException being thrown.